# Rails model test - should_receive method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing a pretty straightforward method. Whenever a referer has referred 5 people to become new users, I want them to get a refund. This means that when a new user is created, there's a method `check_referer` that checks to see if the person who referred them (if this person exists) should get a refund because they've now referred 5 people in total.

In the test logs, based on the `puts` statement, I can tell that the code is working and the `refund_membership_fees_paid` method is indeed being called once. But the test keeps failing with:

```
Failure/Error: @referer.should_receive(:refund_membership_fees_paid).exactly(1).times
   (#<User:0x007fbf46bf1c58>).refund_membership_fees_paid(any args)
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Test code:

```
describe User, "Test refund_membership_fees_paid method is called" do
  before do
    @referer = User.new()
    @referer.save(validate:false)
    RefererRefundAlert.stub_chain(:new, :async, :perform)
  end
  it "at 5 users" do
    5.times do |index|
        u = User.new(referred_by: @referer.id)
        u.save(validate:false)
    end
    @referer.should_receive(:refund_membership_fees_paid).exactly(1).times
  end
end
```

Model code:

```
def check_referer
  if self.referred_by.present? && User.where(referred_by: self.referred_by).count == 5
    User.find(self.referred_by).refund_membership_fees_paid
  end
end

def refund_membership_fees_paid
  puts "refund_membership_fees_paid method"
  RefererRefundAlert.new.async.perform(self.id)
end
```

Comment: have you tried moving the `should_receive` line right before the `5.times` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.find` does not return the same object as `@referer`; it will return a different instance of `User` that represents the same user in the database.

Instead of checking whether `refund_membership_fees_paid` is called, you can verify that the correct user ID is getting passed into`RefererRefundAlert.new.async.perform`.

Also, as others mentioned, you should set your expectation before running the tested methods.

```
RefererRefundAlert.new.async.should_receive(:perform)
      .with(@referer.id).exactly(1).times
5.times do |index|
  u = User.new(referred_by: @referer.id)
  u.save(validate:false)
end
```

Comment: I'm going to use `User.any_instance.should_receive` because it makes my style of tests more readable. But thanks for explaining that the `User.find` doesn't return the same object, I did not know that! And the mis-ordering was a stupid copy & paste mistake...

Answer (score 2):

The use of `should_receive` is to set the expectation for the following action.

For example, if your `account.close` action is supposed to log the closure, the test would be...

```
  logger.should_receive(:account_closed)
  account.close
```

So your example should be restructured to put the test first...

```
@referer.should_receive(:refund_membership_fees_paid).exactly(1).times
5.times {User.new(referred_by: @referer.id).save(validate: false)}
```